# How to set up a health check on an individual GCE - Internal IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, health-check

I want to create an uptime health check for an application running on GCE with Internal IP.

I've noticed that Uptime checks in GCP only supports external IP and health checks only support a GCE with Load Balancer or a Managed Instance group.

Is there a any other GCP way to create a health check? I'm not sure if Cloud functions help.

Answer (score 0):

No need for Managed Instance Group or Load Balancer. **There's a little workaround for this.**

[Create **legacy health check**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/http-health-checks/create) (`http-health-check`)

`$ gcloud compute http-health-checks create chk1
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/*/global/httpHealthChecks/ch3]
NAME  HOST  PORT  REQUEST_PATH
ch3         80    /`

and then create a [target-pool with health check assigned](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-pools/create)

`$ gcloud compute target-pools create tp1 --health-check=chk1
The --health-check flag is deprecated. Use equivalent --http-health-check=chk1 flag.
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/*/regions/my-region1/targetPools/tp1].
NAME  REGION        SESSION_AFFINITY  BACKUP  HEALTH_CHECKS
tp1   my-region1    NONE                      ch3`

Next [add an instance to the target-pool](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/target-pools#add_or_remove_instance_target_pool) (just one).

`gcloud compute target-pools add-instances tp1 --instances test-inst1`

Finally you can [check health](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-pools/get-health) using `gcloud compute target-pools get-health` command.

Comment: Thank you @W_B I've created health check & target pool as specified. However I'm not getting any response back when I do 'get-health' - `gcloud compute http-health-checks describe app checkIntervalSec: 60 creationTimestamp: '2020-06-01T09:21:53.871-07:00' description: '' healthyThreshold: 2 host: 10.x.x.9 (GCE Internal IP) id: '847xx’ kind: compute#httpHealthCheck name: app port: 4040 requestPath: /healthcheck selfLink: xx timeoutSec: 10 unhealthyThreshold: 2`

Comment: But you typed in `gcloud compute http-health-checks describe' - what's the output of `gcloud compute target-pools get-health` ?

Comment: `gcloud compute target-pools get-health app-pool
---
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth`

Comment: There was an error in my reply - instead of `health-check` you have to create a legacy health check `http-health-check` - I edited my answer - please go through it again and let me know.

Comment: Hello W_B, I've created legacy http-health-check here but It doesn't work as expected. As mentioned in previous comment there is a empty reply for that command output.

Comment: @Vihari P - I got the same results (empty reply) too. in this case you may want to try to report a bug on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). Here's some [documentation how to file a bug on IssueTracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui).

Answer (score 0):

As per my research with GCP team, private uptime check EAP is about to release in upcoming month  which might address your issue , as presently its in alpha stage so need to whitelist your project to use this alpha feature.

Comment: Thank you Neelam. An Early Access Program to support Internal IP is slated to start sometime in Q3 which should be in the next 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Private Uptime checks are available as a pre-GA offering:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/private-checks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).